# Rust, same type, different paths from separate imports of the same module

Tags: oop, rust

I am new to Rust, and have gotten some way through writing my first toy program, just a card game implementation. Here is my current file structure:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── card.rs
│   ├── deck.rs
│   ├── hand.rs
│   └── main.rs
```

The basic building block of course being the card struct, it looks like this:

```
pub struct Card {
    value: Value,
    suit: Suit,
    is_visible : bool
}

impl Card {
    pub fn new(value: &Value, suit: &Suit) -> Card {
        Card {...}
    }
}
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Suit {...}
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Value{...}
```

Deck implementation in deck.rs, using the card module:

```
#[path="card.rs"]
mod card;
pub use card::*;

pub struct Deck(Vec<Card>);

impl Deck {
    pub fn new(n_packs: u32) -> Deck {
        let mut cards = Vec::new();
        ...
        Deck(cards)
    }
    pub fn deal_from_top(&mut self, n_cards: u32) -> Vec<Card>{...}
    pub fn shuffle(&mut self) {...}

    ...
}
```

very similar struct, Hand is defined in module hand.rs

```
#[path = "card.rs"]
mod card;
pub use card::*;

pub struct Hand(Vec<Card>);

impl Hand{
    pub fn new(cards: Vec<Card>) -> Hand{
        Hand(cards)
    }
}
```

In main.rs, I have want to

- create a deck,
- shuffle it,
- deal n cards,
- place these cards into a Hand struct

That last one is giving me some serious grief.

Here is what I have tried:

```
mod hand;
mod deck;
use hand::Hand;
use deck::Deck;

fn main() { 
    let mut deck = Deck::new(1);
    deck.shuffle();
    let mut cards = deck.deal_from_top(5);
    let mut hand = Hand::new(cards);
}
```

Which throws a complie-time error E0308:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:30
   |
13 |     let mut hand = Hand::new(cards);
   |                              ^^^^^ expected struct `hand::card::Card`, found struct `deck::card::Card`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<hand::card::Card>`
              found struct `std::vec::Vec<deck::card::Card>`
```

So clearly I am missing something in my understanding of how user-defined types are 'imported' for use.

By importing the cards module, the 'Card' type used by deck, and by hand become separate types as
far as main is concerned. I do not want deck or hand to reference each other to access the same namespaced version of Card.

How can I make the card struct completely reusable in this context? or is my somewhat object-oriented approach just so wide of the mark to not be achievable in idiomatic rust? Searching so far has yielded nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `#[path="card.rs"]` you force your `deck` and `hand` modules to find the `card` **sub**module in a non-standard place.
In `deck.rs` and `hand.rs`, writing `mod card;` considers `card` as a **sub**module of the two previous.
In theory, these submodules should be located in `src/deck/card.rs` and `src/hand/card.rs`, hence the `path=` notation to find these in another place.

Instead of that, you probably want to use the `card` module which is at the same level.
Just get rid of `mod card;` in those two files and write `pub use super::card::*;` instead of `pub use::card::*;`. Finally, add `mod card;` in `main.rs` so that it is discovered when `main.rs` is read by the compiler.

In your solution, reusing the same file for two different submodules was just a trick equivalent to copy/paste but from the language point of view, these two submodules and the struct they provide are distinct (as told by the compiler in the error message).