# Mismatched types with modules

Tags: rust, module

I am making small program for validating and computing IPs.
I wanted to try out modules and I encountered an error I do not know how to solve and can't find anything on the internet.

Here is my project structure:

```
src/
    ip.rs
    main.rs
    mask.rs
    show.rs
```

ip.rs

```rust
pub struct Ip {
    pub first: u8,
    pub second: u8,
    pub third: u8,
    pub forth: u8,

    pub bin: [bool; 32]
}



pub fn build_ip(ip: String) -> Ip {
    let split = ip.replace(".", ":");
    let split = split.split(":");
    let split_vec = split.collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut bin: [bool; 32] = [false; 32];
    let mut octets: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];

    if split_vec.len() != 4 {
        panic!("Wrong amount of octets!");
    }
    for i in 0..4 {
        let octet: u8 = match split_vec[i].trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => panic!("Something wrong with first octet"),
        };
        octets[i] = octet;

        let soctet = format!("{:b}", octet);
        for (j, c) in soctet.chars().enumerate() {
            bin[j + i*8] = c == '1';
        }
    }


    Ip {
        first: octets[0],
        second: octets[1],
        third: octets[2],
        forth: octets[3], 
        bin: bin
    }
}
```

show.rs

```rust
#[path = "ip.rs"] mod ip;
#[path = "mask.rs"] mod mask;

pub use ip::Ip;


pub fn print(name: String, ip: ip::Ip) {
    println!("{}: ", name);
    println!("{}.{}.{}.{}", ip.first, ip.second, ip.third, ip.forth);
    for c in ip.bin.iter() {
        print!("{}", *c as i32);
    }
    println!("");
    println!("");
}
```

main.rs

```rust
pub mod mask;
pub mod ip;
pub mod show;

fn main() {
    let ip = ip::build_ip("255:255:25:8:0".to_string());
    // let mask = mask::build_mask("255.255.255.252".to_string());
    show::print("ip".to_string(), ip)
}
```

When I try to compile it throws this at me and I have no idea what to do:

```
 --> src\main.rs:9:32
  |
9 |     show::print("ip".to_string(), ip)
  |                                   ^^ expected struct `show::ip::Ip`, found struct `ip::Ip`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust, same type, different paths from separate imports of the same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069463/rust-same-type-different-paths-from-separate-imports-of-the-same-module)

Comment: This question has received a better answer; may we close the other as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman no up-votes on the "better answer" and you want to reverse-dupe-close another question for it? I'd support it but the ask feels premature. IMO all answers to this kind of struggle need a big 72-pt font header that says "DON'T USE #[path = ...] !"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> #[path = "ip.rs"] mod ip;
> #[path = "mask.rs"] mod mask;
> ```

This declares new submodules, independent from the ones declared in `mod.rs`. That they have the same source code is immaterial, as far as typechecking and object identity are concerned they're completely unrelated.

Essentially, you've defined the following structure:

```rust
pub mod mask { ... }
pub mod ip {
    pub struct Ip { ... }
    pub fn build_ip(ip: String) -> Ip { ... }
}
pub mod show {
    mod ip  {
        pub struct Ip { ... }
        pub fn build_ip(ip: String) -> Ip { ... }
    }
    mod mask { ... }
    pub fn print(name: String, ip: ip::Ip) { ... }
}
```

If you want to *import* modules, you should use `use`. If you need to import sibling modules, you can use the `crate::` segment (in order to start resolving from the current crate's root), or `super::` (to move up a level from the current module).

So here `show` should contain either `use crate::{ip, mask}` or `use super::{ip, crate}` in order to "see" its siblings.

The `pub` for `use ip::Ip;` is also completely unnecessary, you only needed it because you were declaring a new `ip` module, and thus needed *its* `Ip` to be public since you were using it in a `pub` function.

Answer (score 0):

In `show.rs`, you write add the modules `ip` and `mask`, but these are already added in `main.rs`.

Instead, in `show.rs` use something like the following:

```rust
use crate::ip::Ip;

pub fn print(name: String, ip: Ip) {
    ...
}
```